# Call wx Dialog from pygame App and return a value

Tags: python, wxpython, pygame

I am trying to get some value from a wx dialog which I run from my pygame app. I am totally new to wxPython and never did any OOP, so I need some help. Now it is kind of working, at least the dialog shows up and closes successfully. But I don't have an idea what I need to add to my dialog methods to handle the input from the dialog after it is closed. I place the relevant code here. It uses examples from http://zetcode.com/wxpython/dialogs/
My `dial.py` module :

```
import wx

class OptionsDial(wx.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(OptionsDial, self).__init__(*args, **kw) 

        self.InitUI()
        self.SetSize((300, 200))
        self.SetTitle("Import options")


    def InitUI(self):

        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        sb = wx.StaticBox(pnl, label='Import')
        sbs = wx.StaticBoxSizer(sb, orient=wx.VERTICAL)        
        sbs.Add(wx.RadioButton(pnl, label='PNG', style=wx.RB_GROUP))
        sbs.Add(wx.RadioButton(pnl, label='TIFF'))
        sbs.Add(wx.RadioButton(pnl, label='JPEG'))

        pnl.SetSizer(sbs)

        hbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        okButton = wx.Button(self, label='Ok')
        closeButton = wx.Button(self, label='Close')
        hbox2.Add(okButton)
        hbox2.Add(closeButton, flag=wx.LEFT, border=5)

        vbox.Add(pnl, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, border=5)
        vbox.Add(hbox2, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, border=10)

        self.SetSizer(vbox)

        okButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)
        closeButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)

    def OnClose(self, e):
        self.Destroy()
        self.Close()
```

Note that I had to add `self.Close()` line in onClose method, otherwise it doesn't work at all. And in my main program I call it like that (it doesn't read the selected option, now I just try to make it return some different result depending on what button is pressed now and I am stuck):

```
def options() :
    ff = "PNG"
    app = wx.App(None)
    dlg = dial.OptionsDial(None)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK :
        ff = "JPG"      
    return ff
```

Now my function returns "PNG" always. So how do I make it return a value depending on :
1. Selected radio button (actually I need the index of the radio button only)
2. Pressed button (Ok or Close in this case)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly the zetcode `wx.Dialog` example at the end of the page is neither pretty smart nor sensible. Do not destroy the Dialog in the dialog.

```
def OnClose(self, e):
    # self.Destroy()
    self.Close()
```

Destroy it afterwards, so that you can readout settings beforehand.

```
def options() :
    ff = "PNG"
    app = wx.App(None)
    dlg = dial.OptionsDial(None)
    res = dlg.ShowModal()
    if res == wx.ID_OK :
        if dlg.radio_png.GetValue() == True:
            # Yay it is PNG!
            ff = 'PNG'
        # and so on for other possibilities
    dlg.Destroy() # now it is time to destroy it
    return ff
```

Of course to be able to readout your Radio selection, you have to make the RBs accessible from outside of the `wx.Dialog` instance.

```
    self.radio_png = wx.RadioButton(pnl, label='PNG', style=wx.RB_GROUP))
    ...
    sbs.Add(self.radio_png)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working now. I have realised the problem - in the example the 'okButton' was bound to 'onClose' method and it was just closing the Dialog on click so I've commented out that line and now I can return the value correctly.

Comment: Using EndModal instead of Close is the preferred way for wx.Dialogs.  Or you could use the stock wx.ID_OK and wx.ID_CANCEL IDs for the buttons and then let wx take care of the button event handlers for you.